# Nesting placeholders in Standard Values

Tags: jss, content-editor, placeholders

I know (and I do it) that I can put a default value in a placeholder so that when I create a new item for my route type it populates my placeholder with a component that I will choose.

I do it like that :

- In the Content Editor I get on sitecore > Templates > Project > My Project > My RouteType > __Standard Value
- I choose the Presentation Tab and I click on details
- Then I click on Edit and in the new window I click on the Control Tab
- I click add and I can choose a component and assing it to a placeholder by putting the name in Placeholder [shared] (for example /jss-main if jss-main is my placeholder name)
- Then when I create a new route type I automatically get the choosen component in my jss-main placeholder.

So this is working and I'm happy with it. What I would like to know is if it is possible to put a placeholder inside another one so that I'll get a component inside another one.

Let's take one example :

- I have a route type for a glossary
- I have a default layout that has a placeholder called jss-main
- I have a component called two-columns that has two placeholders column-1 and column-2
- I have a component that is name simple-text that has no placeholder

I would like to put in jss-main a component two-columns and in the placeholders column-1 and column-2 from this component put two different simple-text components.

Is it possible to do so and if yes what should I put in the placeholders fields ?

A screenshot of my attempt to include one in another
[image]

Here is a picture of the experience editor when creating a page with the placeholders like that.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope below is the structure of the layout.
[image]

As you mentioned you have applied component in `jss-main` placeholder which is correct.

1. You can apply `two-column` component on `jss-main` placeholder which will be like this `/jss-main/two-column`
2. Now to apply `simple-text` component on `Column1` and `Column2`, you can apply `simple-text` component like this `/jss-main/column1/simple-text` and `/jss-main/column2/simple-text`

**More Detail:**

1. I have created a layout where I defined placeholder `@Html.Sitecore().Placeholder("jss-main")`

[image]

2.Created Two-Column view html `TwoColumn.cshtml`

[image]

3. Created rendering for "TwoColumn"
   [image]
4. Created placeholder

[image]

5. Finally, add rendering in standard value of a page template

[image]

Comment: Thank you, you understood the problem well, the structure is correct. Do I need to sort my items or could they be in any order ?

Comment: This could be in any order

Comment: It seems that I'm unable to do it : jss-main contain my two-columns component but I'm unable to put my simple text component into it. Is it possible to create items like that ?

Comment: can you please share screen shot what you have done?

Comment: Here is a screenshot https://ibb.co/VMpDjtG the container names are not the same because I'm trying on a simple example : include in jss-main ContentPageMainContainer that contains another placeholder named body-contents and then I'm trying to put in body contents a component name Single column container. After that I'll include another level but I think that if it works with 2 levels it will work for three.

Comment: @Christophe sorry I am not able to open screenshot

Comment: Currently theses settings create only the ContentPageMainContainer and I have to put then manually my other items.

Comment: I've added the image in the question

Comment: placeholder name should be "/jss-main/body-contents" not "jss-main/body-contents"

Comment: I've tried with /jss-main and /jss-main/body-contents and all combinations of / in front of it or without it and I always have the same kind of behavior : ContentPageMainContainer is added to the page but not the Single column container

Comment: Are you able to see component when you are appling component on page using experience editor instead of standard value? Apply component via experience editor and then check placeholder path in presentation detail.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97976/discussion-between-christophe-and-swati-gupta).